# Time not saving in database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

OK, here is my scenario. After my games finish, a user is provided with his time in which he finished the game, and right after that my dialog.theme activity pops up for user name input. The name is stored in sqlite database. And now my problem....the time IS NOT. The time is stored in a variable of double type. It works fine when I send that value to my RezultatVreme.class (then I use it in my popup activity in which I present the time to the user...it happens right before my input name popup). Now, I use the same value and send it to my ImePopup.class, and use that class when use enters his name to pass the time value and enter it in my database. But it's not working. My name is entered fine, but the time is always 0. I tried with double, integer and long, but it the same result. Here's my game class, part of it, where I present the popups and pass value to my other classes:

```
long tEnd = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long tDelta = tEnd - tStart;
            elapsedSeconds = tDelta / 1000.0;

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RezultatVreme.class);
            i.putExtra("novoVreme", elapsedSeconds);
            startActivity(i);
            Intent ip = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ImePopup.class);
            ip.putExtra("score", elapsedSeconds);
            startActivity(ip);
```

Here's my popup class:

```
public class ImePopup extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    EditText ime;
    Button ok, odustani;
    double score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.imepopup);

        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btOK);
        odustani = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btOdustani);
        ime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIme);

        ok.setOnClickListener(this);
        odustani.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        switch (arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.btOK:
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try{
            String name = ime.getText().toString();

            OffDBHelper entry = new OffDBHelper(ImePopup.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name, score);
            entry.close();
            break;
            }catch(Exception e){
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Greska!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Greska u upisu");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }finally{
                if(didItWork){
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Uspesno!");
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Upisali ste se!");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();
                }
            }
        case R.id.btOdustani:

            break;
}
    }
}
```

And my OffDBHelper class:

```
public class OffDBHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_SCORE = "score";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "highscores";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "highscorestable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

        public DbHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                    KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + 
                    KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                    KEY_SCORE + " DOUBLE NOT NULL);"
                    );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);       
        }

    }

    public OffDBHelper(Context c){
        ourContext = c;
    }

    public OffDBHelper open() throws Exception{
        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }
    public void close(){
        ourHelper.close();
    }

    public long createEntry(String name, double score) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        cv.put(KEY_SCORE, score);
        return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
    }

    public String getData() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        String result = "";

        int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
        int iScore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iName) + " " + c.getString(iScore) + "\n";
        }

        return result;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call the DBHelper in ImePopup like that

```
OffDBHelper entry = new OffDBHelper(ImePopup.this);
entry.open();
entry.createEntry(name, score);
entry.close();
```

but you never write data to your variable `score` so it has always its initial value which is 0.

You need to extract your "score" out of the `Intent` first

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot about that little thing. Thanks alot. I will post my correction in last post in case someone else needs it.

Answer (score 0):

```
double score;
double scoreR;



Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
        if(extras !=null) {
           scoreR = extras.getDouble("score", 0);
        }


OffDBHelper entry = new OffDBHelper(ImePopup.this);
            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(name, scoreR);
            entry.close();
```